# Ant script generate a findbugs_result.xml, but the hudson can not display on main interface. why?

Tags: hudson, findbugs

Findbugs script in build.xml:
    
  Findbugs checks Coding...
  
   
   
   
  
  Findbugs checks Coding...

genetate a findbugs_result.xml.

Download Findbugs plugin for hudson.

Enter findbugs_result.xml path for hudson.

But hudson can not display on main interface. why?

Comment: check your logfiles for error messages

Answer (score 1):

I've found some annoying inconsistencies in the way Hudson stores paths; sometimes you use the overall workspace directory for the Hudson job and other times you have to use the path to the code that the job checks out of source control.  For example, if your code gets checked out to MyProject under your workspace directory, and then the test XML files go into MyProject/target/test-reports, try specifying the path with and without the MyProject at the beginning of the path.